# In a sed transformation, how to apply a slightly different pattern just for the last line?

Tags: sed

How can I turn this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

into this:

```
aaa,
bbb,
ccc
```

using `sed`?

Note how all lines end a comma, except the last one.

In my real problem I also do some regex substitutions on the lines. Is there a solution that doesn't duplicate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
sed '$q;s/$/,/'
```

If you want to apply a different substitution on the last line, you can still use the `$` address:

```
sed '$s/$/;/;$q;s/$/,/'
```

The above will replace the end of the line with `;` if it's the last line, otherwise it will use `,`.

1. `$s/$/;/` = at the last line, replace the end of the line with `;`
2. `$q` = at the last line, quit
3. `s/$/,/` = replace the end of the line with `,`

The last `s` command will run for each line, but not for the last line in which the `q` command at 2. tells it to quit.

---

See:

- [Restricting to a line number](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-26)
- [Ranges by line number](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-28)
- [The q or quit command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-34)

Comment: This did the trick - giving sed two commands separately makes it work in a pipeline and avoided the duplication.